# `gh cli` fails `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)` but no problem with `gh desktop`

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github, github-cli

I'm a bit ashamed to admit that so far I used [github desktop](https://dev.to/rahedmir/is-github-desktop-available-for-gnu-linux-4a69)
and I'm now determined to try using [gh cli](https://cli.github.com/)
I installed following the [documentation](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md#debian-ubuntu-linux-apt)

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key C99B11DEB97541F0
sudo apt-add-repository https://cli.github.com/packages
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gh
```

with apparent success

```sh
$ which gh
/usr/bin/gh
$ gh --version
gh version 1.8.1 (2021-04-02)
https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v1.8.1
```

but to clone a public repo (for example [flutter gallery](https://github.com/flutter/gallery)) running `gh repo clone flutter/gallery`
I get the following error

```sh
Cloning into 'gallery'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
exit status 128
```

(everithing worked "*out-of-the-box*" with `gh-desktop`)
what am I missing?

[github discussion](https://github.com/cli/cli/discussions/3389)

Comment: Please post [mre] of program you are writing and describe the problem you are having with it.

Comment: @stark I'm not writing any program and I believe I provided clear steps to reproduce the behavior I'm experiencing, if some step is unclear or more information is required I ask you to be more specific; do you have any experience with `gh cli` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as authentication is required even to clone a public repository
running [gh auth login](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) fixes the issue
I've open an [issue](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/3401) proposing a `clearer authentication error message`

Answer (score 2):

Check first if you have the same issue using `ssh` directly:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

If that is the case, check your `~/.ssh` content, and make sure you have [added](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) and then [tested](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/testing-your-ssh-connection) an SSH key in order for said key to work from command line (since GitHub Desktop might manage its own key internally to the GitHub Desktop application)